# Use Singleton in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, singleton

I thought something like this with the use of Singleton pattern. I don't want serious methods or classes or anything. Here I what is something like this.

```
private void btnVehicleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {}
```

This is my *Events-> Action-> **actionPerformed*** of jButton **btnVehicle**. When I press the button an InternalFrame Form is loaded to a jDesktopPane. When I pressed twice two Forms are loaded. If I can use Singleton, it's the best solution to load single Frame and bring the Frame front if it is already loaded. I tried, actually this didn't work, singleton to the button.

```
Registration_Vehicles rv;
private void btnVehicleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    if(rv==null){
        rv = new Registration_Vehicles();
        jDesktopPane2.add(rv);
    }        
    else{
    rv.toFront();
    }
}
```

Can anyone give a better solution for this with singleton or anything else..

Comment: I don't think what your describing would be singlton per-say.  You might have a "factory" which is associated with a `JDesktop` which maintains information about the windows it's created/are in the `JDesktop` for example, this way, when you want to create a window, you would pass the required information to the factory and the factory would pass back an instance of `JInternalFrame` based on what it knows (create/re-use)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small program that can either select an existing internal frame or create a new one (depending on whether a user specified frame number already exists):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SingletonInSwing {
    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
    private JTextField frameNumberTextField;

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new SingletonInSwing().launchGui();
    }

    private void launchGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        desktopPane.add(createControlPanel());

        // Add one internal frame to get started.
        addInternalFrame("1");

        frame.setContentPane(desktopPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JInternalFrame createControlPanel() {
        final JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        frameNumberTextField = new JTextField(6);
        final JButton addFrameButton = new JButton("Add internal frame");
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("Frame number:"));
        controlPanel.add(frameNumberTextField);
        controlPanel.add(addFrameButton);

        frameNumberTextField.addActionListener(actionEvent -> addInternalFrame());
        addFrameButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> addInternalFrame());

        final JInternalFrame controlFrame = new JInternalFrame("Control frame");
        controlFrame.add(controlPanel);
        controlFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 760, 90);
        controlFrame.setVisible(true);

        return controlFrame;
    }

    private void addInternalFrame() {
        addInternalFrame(frameNumberTextField.getText());
    }

    private void addInternalFrame(final String frameNumber) {
        final String frameTitle = "test " + frameNumber;

        // Search for existing frame.
        JInternalFrame existingFrame = null;
        for (final JInternalFrame internalFrame : desktopPane.getAllFrames()) {
            if (frameTitle.equals(internalFrame.getTitle())) {
                existingFrame = internalFrame;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Select existing or create new frame.
        if (existingFrame != null) {
            try {
                existingFrame.setSelected(true);
            } catch (final PropertyVetoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            final int frameCount = desktopPane.getAllFrames().length;
            final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame(frameTitle);
            internalFrame.setBounds(20 * frameCount, 110 + 40 * frameCount, 400, 200);
            internalFrame.setVisible(true);
            desktopPane.add(internalFrame);
            internalFrame.moveToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a nice tutorial on `JDesktopPane` and `JInternalFrame`s over here: [The Java Tutorials - How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).